# JVM settings: can't increase heap size over 2GB

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm, heap-memory

i need to increase the JVM over 2GB. This is my java version:

```
[arturo@X550LD bin]$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
```

I'm running on a arch-based distro x64, my current IDE is IntelliJ 2017.3.

I've already tried to change idea64.vmoptions file, this is my configuration:

```
-Xms3072m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine
```

When I try to run "Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()", the method returns only 1834483712

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use 64 bit Java.

Comment: I'm already on 64 bit Java. "System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")" returns 64

Comment: My guess is that heap for IntelliJ is 4gb, but the program you are trying to run inside IntelliJ is using default JVM options. Take a look at the right bottom corner in Intellij there should be something like 500 from 4G (heap size). If you want to change JVM args for app run from intellij you should do that in Run Configuration

Comment: Yes, i think the same! But i don't know how to force my application to allocate 4 GB heapspace or make 4G the default heapsize space

Comment: Ok i found the answer:
Run -> edit configuration -> VM options -> -Xmx4096m
Thanks!